# NullReferenceException error in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, oop, nullreferenceexception

In the below code I am getting a `Null Reference Exception` error while using `"Names.Add(string)"` method. But when I use a static class or a static object of the `NamedDB` class it works fine. Can any one explain how object instances work in ASP.Net web applications ? Why am I getting errors in nonstatic objects while static objects are working fine ?

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

   NameDB Names; //Creating Object

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Names = new NameDB();//Instantiation
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Names.Add("dss");//Object Reference is null

        GridView1.DataSource = Names.GetName();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}


    //NamedDB class

    public class NameDB
    {
        List<string> Names=new List<string>();

        public void Add(string item)
        {
            Names.Add(item);
        }

        public string Remove(string item)
        {

            Names.Remove(item);
            return item;
        }

        public List<string> GetName()
        {

            return Names;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have instances of global object which are instantiated before post back. Instantiate the object again in `Button1_Click`

Now You would be expecting the collection to hold data between post back but you wont get it until you store it some where like `database`, `files`,`session`, `viewstate` or `cache` for data. Session and ViewState are not meant for storing that type of data though.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Names = new NameDB();//Instantiation
    Names.Add("dss");//Object Reference is null
    GridView1.DataSource = Names.GetName();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: But this way you will never get more than that single "dss" name, because the "NameDB" is recreated for every call.

Comment: Thanks Adil, Can you please also tell me how it works in case of static ? 

if  "static NameDB Name" it works.

Comment: I understand that static collection will be same for all  users. I want to know how static saves in memory in case of WEB.

Comment: You can use cache but you should be careful about the size of data you need to store, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
NameDB Names; //Creating Object
```

by this

```
NameDB Names = new NameDB(); //Creating Object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do any of following

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   NameDB Names= new NameDB();//Creating Object
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Names.Add("dss");

        GridView1.DataSource = Names.GetName();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

or

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   NameDB Names;//Creating Object
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Names = new NameDB();//Instantiation
        Names.Add("dss");

        GridView1.DataSource = Names.GetName();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the page-object is recreated for every request. So page-level fields are re-initialized for every call. And a postback is just another request!

If you want to persist values between requests, you need to find some way to store these.
Some options are:

- In a real database, takes some work but you have full control and full persistence
- In [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.cache.aspx) or [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.application.aspx), for application-wide storage where every visitor gets the same values, but these are lost when the app recycles.
- In [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.session.aspx), for user-specific storage as long as the session doesn't time out (and the app doesn't recycle)
- In [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate.aspx), for "postback-specific" storage: this will keep values through postbacks to the same page (user-specific), but are lost when the user goes to another page.